# Копирую один input в другой но не знаю как добавить доп значение

Tags: javascript

Поделитесь пожалуйста примером, не могу найти.

Копирую значение одного input в другой, но не знаю как добавить текст в начале и позади
Типа: Текст1 копируемый текст Текст2

Вот нашел скрипт который копирует:

```js
var inputname1 = document.getElementById("input-name1");
var inputmetatitle1 = document.getElementById("input-meta-title1");
function dmcopyinputRU()
{
inputmetatitle1.value = inputname1.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="dmcopyinputRU();" value="" id="input-name1"/>
<input type="text"  value="" id="input-meta-title1"/>
```

Подправьте пожалуйста

Comment: ничего не понял, вам поменять последний символ скопированного текста надо?

Comment: `inputmetatitle1.value = 'Текст1' + inputname1.value + 'Текст2';`

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто конкатенируйте то что есть.

```js
var inputname1 = document.getElementById("input-name1");
var inputmetatitle1 = document.getElementById("input-meta-title1");

function dmcopyinputRU() {
    inputmetatitle1.value = 'Текст1 ' + inputname1.value + ' Текст2';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="dmcopyinputRU();" value="" id="input-name1"/>
<input type="text"  value="" id="input-meta-title1"/>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!